# Не отправляются данные в php файл для расчетов

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Не понимаю, где еще здесь кроется ошибка. Везде, где сервер ее выдавал - исправил. Сейчас не работает, но и ошибок не выводит.
Файл index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>MonteCarlo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
    var vars = "";
    if(this.innerHTML == "Вычислить"){      
    vars=$("form").serialize();
    }else{
        vars = "Ax=15&Bx=10&Ay=0&By=5";
    }                 
         $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "calc.php",
                            data: vars,
                            beforeSend: function(){
                            $("#ans").html;
                        },                      
                            success: function(data) {
                                $("#ans").html(data);
                            }
                        });     
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><p class="title">Метод Монте-Карло</p></div>
<div class="iMage">Исходное изображение<br/> <img src="1.png"/></div>
<div id="form_div">
    <form action="#" method="POST" id="form">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td><input class = "XY" name ="Ax"/></td>
        <td><input class = "XY" name ="Bx"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>E</td>
        <td><input class = "XY" name ="Ay"/></td>
        <td><input class = "XY" name ="By"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!--<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Рассчитать площадь">-->
    <div class="button"><a href="#">Рассчитать площадь</a></div>
        <div class="button"><a href="#">Контрольный пример</a></div>
    </form>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="ans"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Файл calc.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["Ax"])){

            $W = new Point($_POST["Ax"]-$_POST["Bx"], $_POST["By"]); 
            $D = new Point($_POST["Ax"], $_POST["Ay"]);
            $E = new Point($_POST["Bx"], $_POST["By"]);
            $F = new Point($_POST["Ax"]-$_POST["Bx"], $_POST["Ay"]);
            $C = new Point($_POST["Ax"], $_POST["By"]);
            $O = new Point($_POST["Bx"], $_POST["Ay"]);

            $R = ($E->Y - $O->Y) / 4;

                $a = $W->Y - $F->Y;
                $b = $C->X - $W->X;

                $square = $a * $b; 


                $WF = sqrt(pow($W->X - $F->X))+(pow($W->Y - $F->Y));
                $FD = sqrt(pow($F->X - $D->X))+(pow($F->Y - $D->Y));
                $EO = sqrt(pow($E->X - $O->X))+(pow($E->Y - $O->Y));
                $FO = sqrt(pow($F->X - $O->X))+(pow($F->Y - $O->Y));

                $rctngl = $WF * $FD; //rectangle
                $trngl = ($EO * $FO) / 2; //triangle
                $crcl = (3.14 * pow($R, 2)) /4; //circle

                $squareF =  Square($trngl, $crcl); // площадь фигуры
                echo 'Общая площадь : '.$squareF.'  <br/>'; 
                $k = 0;
                $fori = 100;
             echo '<div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Кол-во испытаний
                        </td>
                        <td >
                           Кол-во попавших точек
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Площадь фигуры
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Погрешность, %
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Время, мс
                        </td>
                    </tr>
               ';

                while ($k < 5)
               {
         $vremiya_starta = microtime(true);
                    $inF = 0; $outF = 0;
                   for ($i = 0; $i < $fori; $i++)
                    {
                        $x = random_float($F->X,$C->X);
                        $y = random_float($D->Y,$E->Y);

                        if (IsInFigure($x,$y,$D,$E,$F))
                        {
                            $inF++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $outF++;
                        }
                    }

                   $s = $square * ($inF / $fori);

                    $vremya_okonchaniya = microtime(true);
                    $vremya = $vremya_okonchaniya - $vremiya_starta;
                    $vremya = round($vremya*1000);
                   echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.
                            $fori.'
                        </td>
                        <td >'.
                          $inF.'
                        </td>
                        <td>'.
                            $s.'
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        '.round((Different($trngl, $crcl, $s)),4).'
                        </td>
            <td>'.
                           ($vremya).'
                        </td>
                    </tr>';

                    $k++;
                    $fori *= 10;
                }
                echo ' </table>
            </div>';
}
class Point{
    var $X;
    var $Y;

    function __construct($X, $Y){
    $this->X = $x;
    $this->Y = $y;
    }
}
function random_float ($min,$max) {
   return ($min+lcg_value()*(abs($max-$min)));
}

    function IsInFigure($x, $y, $D,$E,$F,$P)
        { 
            if ($P < $E->X)
            {
                if (IsInTriangle($P))
                return true;
            else
                if (IsInCircle($P))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    function IsInCircle($X, $Y, $E, $O)
        {  
            Point vect = new Point();
            vect.X = $E->X - $P-X;
            vect.Y = $O->Y - $P-Y;
            $R = $E->Y - $P->Y;
            $Q->X = pow(vect.X, 2); $Q->Y = pow(vect.Y, 2);
            $vect_length = sqrt($Q->X + $Q->Y);
            if ($vect_length <= $R)
                return true;
            return false;   
        }

        function IsInTriangle($X, $Y, $E, $F, $O)
        {
           $E = ($F->X - $P->X) * ($E->Y - $F->Y) - ($E->X - $F->X) * ($F->Y - $P->Y);
           $F = ($E->X - $P->X) * ($E->Y - $E->Y) - ($F->X - $E->X) * ($E->Y - $P->Y);
           $O = ($F->X - $P->X) * ($F->Y - $E->Y) - ($F->X - $F->X) * ($F->Y - $P->Y);
           return (($E >= 0 && $F >= 0 && $O >= 0) || ($E <= 0 && $F <= 0 && $O <= 0));
        }

        function Square($r, $d, $e, $f, $o)
        {
            $Rc = (3.14 * pow($R, 2)) /4;
            $p = ($EO * $FO) / 2;
            $Rt = $WF * $FD;
            return $Rc + $p;
        }
function Different($r, $d, $e, $f, $o, $nowS)
{
$Rc = (3.14 * pow($R, 2)) /4;
            $p = ($EO * $FO) / 2;
            $Rt = $WF * $FD;
return abs((($Rc + $p) - $nowS)/($Rc + $p));
}
?>
```

Честно говоря, все идеи уже закончились

Answer (score 0):

```
vars = $("#form").serialize();
```

Comment: опять начинает кричать на ошибку в calc.php Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in Z:\home\localhost\www\calc.php on line 130, на той строке находится function IsInCircle($X, $Y, $E, $O), если закомментировать, то долго думает страница и сваливается в ошибку